# The proofs of theorems vs the proof of theorems

Tags: expression-choice

Suppose that there are three Theorems, say Theorem A, Theorem B and Theorem C.

I want to refer all of proofs of Theorem A,B,C at the same time.

Which one is correct?

1. From the proofs of Theorem A,B and C, ~~
2. From the proof of Theorem A, B and C, ~

Comment: Version 1 is definitely preferable, but you should say *From the proofs of **Theorems** A,B and C,...*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If somebody published a proof of a certain generalized theorem subsuming theorems A, B, and C at once, then number 2 would be the preferred choice. Otherwise number 1.

Comment: Cool construction to make the 2nd one work :)

Comment: But in **both** cases, *Theorem* should be plural because there are 3 theorems.